# Read single or two words from file with help of regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a txt file with following:

```
one two, three, four five, six seven, eight, nine, ten
```

Can you help me write that regexp right to read one OR two words (with white space)?

Need that:

```
stroke[0] = "one two",

stroke[1] = "three",

stroke[2] = "four five",

stroke[3] = "six seven",

stroke[4] = "eight",
...
```

My code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skills));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            stroke[n] += sc.next("\\w|\\w\\s\\w");
            n++;
        }
```

Comment: How about split on commas then clean up the trailing spaces? Also, you need quantifiers in your regex. `\\w` matches a single character, not a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just use `.split(", ")` but if you must use regex, you could use this:

The regex:

```
([^,]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/cR0sV4

Java:

**Note, I am not experienced in java syntax, however it would go something like this.. (Please forgive me if this is not exactly correct java syntax.)

```
String str = "one two, three, four five, six seven, eight, nine, ten";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^,]+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

 while (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(trim(matcher.group()));
 }
```

Note the `trim()` to remove any preceding whitespace.

Something like that..  Again, I don't know java, but the regex works. See example. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = {one two, three, four five, six seven, eight, nine, ten}

String[] string = str.split(",\\s+");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the convention is the file to have this format then you can get the same result if you use the `useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*)` on the Scanner, like

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.skills)).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");`